# JavaScript breaks when reading a self closing tag in XML

Tags: javascript, xml

I am writing a XML file into a HTML file using JavaScript.

Here is the JavaScript I am using:

```
if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else{
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","file.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("tagParent");

document.write(x.getElementsByTagName("tagChild")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

The script will working for everything except for self closing xml elements (`<element/>`).

Example XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<tagParent>
    <tagChild/>
</tagParent>
```

The script breaks and stops when it reaches a self closing tag.

What do I need to do to get it either output 0 or ""?  Why is it breaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is breaking because the element is empty. It doesn't have any children so when you try to get the `nodeValue` of the first child, it errors because `undefined` doesn't have a `0` property.

You want something along the lines of:

```
var dataNodes, value;
dataNodes = x.getElementsByTagName("tagChild")[0].childNodes;
if (dataNodes.length) {
    value = dataNodes[0].nodeValue;
} else {
    value = 0;
}
document.write(value);
```

Comment: What is the logic I could use to get around this.  I have tried this code but it doesn't work: `if (x.getElementsByTagName("tagChild").parentNode !== null){`